# iOS MapKit Zooming display annotations x 2

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am attempting to send the annotations that are currently in the maprect to a class to parse.

When I load my map it loads the correct number of annotations. In this case lets say 2. When I listen in on this function

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
     NSLog("Getting current annotations: \(Array(myMapView.annotations(in: myMapView.visibleMapRect)).count)")
}
```

When I zoom and that function gets called the number of annotations doubles? So it goes from 2 to 4. It never doubles again no matter how far you actually zoom in, and the number of annotations on the map are 2. I have zero clue where it's getting doubled from.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: can you add your full code for your ViewController?

Comment: I think your problem is related to other part of you code, zoom don't have to add duplicated annotations, so please post your code to help you